# error redirect in meta tag IE

Tags: php, redirect, meta-tags, meta

I try to redirect a link by meta tag "refresh".
The all is fine, but the redirect in the IE doesn't redirect to the right link.
For example in the code:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=341598&error_url=http://www.booking.com/?aid=341598;&si=ai,co,ci,re,di&label=normandymainbox&lang=he&ifl=&ss=נורמנדי&checkin_monthday=19&checkin_year_month=2014-4&checkout_monthday=20&checkout_year_month=2014-4&email=">
```

in all the browser it's redirect to:
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=341598&error_url=http://www.booking.com/?aid=341598;&si=ai,co,ci,re,di&label=normandymainbox&lang=he&ifl=&ss=%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%99&checkin_monthday=19&checkin_year_month=2014-4&checkout_monthday=20&checkout_year_month=2014-4&email=

but in IE, the browser redirect to:
http://www.booking.com/?aid=341598errorc_not_specific_enough=city;errorc_not_specific_enough=country;errorc_not_specific_enough=iata;errorc_not_specific_enough=airport;errorc_not_specific_enough=pos;errorc_not_specific_enough=latitude;errorc_not_specific_enough=longitude;errorc_not_specific_enough=region;errorc_not_specific_enough=district;errorc_not_specific_enough=hotelids;errorc_not_specific_enough=text;errorc_not_specific_enough=chaincode;errorc_not_specific_enough=chain;errorc_not_specific_enough=citypart;errorc_not_specific_enough=landmark;errorc_not_specific_enough=box;errorc_not_specific_enough=flash_deals;errorc_not_specific_enough=dest_type;errorc_not_specific_enough=vendor;errorc_not_specific_enough=building;errorv_property_room_info=1;errorv_class_interval=1;errorv_interval_of_time=undef;errorv_review_score_group=empty;errorv_error_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2F%3Faid%3D341598;errorv_csflt=%7B%7D;errorv_ssb=empty

This is the link for the site:
http://נורמנדי.com/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%99/
When you click in the orange button you will be redirected

How could solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way IE is generating all that based on the URL you show, so the problem must lie in the code that generates that HTML.

Comment: Can you explain more please ? What could be the problem ?

Comment: I have no idea - it's in code that you haven't shown us. Maybe search your code for "errorc_not_specific_enough"